# How to get courses that will start next moths and not starting in the current month using laravel eloquent and Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following courses table :

```
------
courses
--------------------------------
  id            starting_date
-------         -------------
   1             2020-10-05
   2             2020-11-15
   3             2020-12-01
   4             2020-12-20
----------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve the courses that will start next months.

```
$courses = Course::where('status',1)
     ->where('starting_date','>=', Carbon::now()->addMonth())
     ->orderBy('starting_date','desc')->get();
```

The problem is that my query retrieves the records of this month and next months records
and I don't to retrieve courses starting at this month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the first  of the next month using Carbon:

```
  $nextMonthFirstDay=(new  Carbon('first day of next month'))->startOfDay();


        $courses = Course:: where('status',1)
            ->where("starting_date",'>=',$nextMonthFirstDay)
          
            ->orderBy('starting_date','desc')->get();
```

Comment: Your answer is great but I want to get the records of the coming months not only next month's records. => November, December and  even next year's months. @OMR

Comment: if so, remove : >where('starting_date','<=',$nextMonthLastDay)

Comment: I did so, but it retrieved only the records of this month and next month. It seems that it retrieves the records that will start at this month until the last day of next month only while I don't want the records of the current month but records starting from next month and after.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tested it, so let me know if it doesn't work.

As I understand it you want courses that'll start next month. This should work:

```
$courses = Course::where('status',1)
   ->whereRaw('starting_date > LAST_DAY('. date('Y-m-d') .')')
   ->orderBy('starting_date','desc')->get();
```

This will get all the courses where starting_date is greater than the last day of any give month